# Java - Two buffered writers

Tags: java, bufferedwriter

Hello all ive been having issues with my BufferedWriter. at first i only had 1 buffered writer the 1 that is showed as `cc` and this worked perfectly along with the output but now that i have tried to implement 2 i continue to get an error else where

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Statement
    - Syntax error, insert "Finally" to complete
```

Here is the code. The error starts at the `}else if (command.equals("action 2"))` line

```
if (selected) {
    if (command.equals("action1")) { 
      BufferedWriter aa;
      try {
          File writerB = new File("output1.txt"); //set transaction-list.txt to be the destination file when writeTransactions is used
          if (!writerB.exists()) {
               writerB.createNewFile();
                    }                           

        FileWriter bb = new FileWriter(writeBalance, true); //filewriter
        aa = new BufferedWriter(bb); // bufferedwriter

      BufferedWriter cc;
            try {  
                int x=0;
                File writerT = new File("output2.txt"); //set transaction-list.txt to be the destination file when writeTransactions is used
                if (!writerT.exists()) {
                    writerT.createNewFile();
                    }
                FileWriter dd = new FileWriter(writeTransactions, true); //filewriter
                cc = new BufferedWriter(dd); // bufferedwriter
                String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator"); //creates a line separator which will be used with string newLine 

        if (n==0) {
            bw.write(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.SHORT).format(now) + newLine);
            wb.write(c);}
            bw.close;
            wb.close}

    }else if (command.equals("action 2"))
```

Comment: Please format your code to be easier to read! Also, what is after this code?

Comment: This is 2015 so please use java.nio.file (just for example: you don't check for the result of `File.createNewFile()`). See [here](http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Using_the_java.nio.file_API) and [here](http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Why_File_sucks).

Comment: I would strongly advise you to indent your code properly (most IDEs have a menu option for this). This would help you to see where you have an unmatched `{` as well as help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't handle your resources properly; for one they should be closed in `finally` blocks...

... However, there is even better and that is to use a try-with-resources statement, along with the new java.nio.file API:

```
final Path file1 = Paths.get("output1.txt");
final Path file2 = Paths.get("output2.txt");

try (
    final BufferedWriter writer1 = Files.newBufferedWriter(file1, StandardCharsets.UTF_8,
        StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
    final BufferedWriter writer2 = Files.newBufferedWriter(file2, StandardCharsets.UTF_8,
        StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
) {
    // use writer1 and writer2 here.
    // Note that BufferedWriter has a .newLine() method as well.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not make a `catch` block after the `try` - in neither cases. A `catch` or a `finally` block is *mandatory* after `try`.

As it was mentioned, the try-with-resources statement introduced in Java 7, is strongly recommended.

Comment: When i add a catch it makes the `FileWriter bb = new FileWriter(writeBalance, true); aa = new BufferedWriter(bb);` which is after the try out of scope

Comment: Of course it is. Declare `FileWriter` outside the `try` block.